# Is there a way to list the file extension of all files in a directory node.js?

Tags: node.js, fs

So when I use `fs.readdir()` I only get the file name and if I use `.split(".")` it wont work since if I have a folder called `a.exe` it will say that `.exe` is the extension even that it's not since folders don't have a extension.

Here is the code for `fs.readdir()`

```
fs.readdir("./", (err,data)=>{
  if (err) throw err
  console.log(data)
})
```

Console: (`a.exe` is a folder and `aa.exe` is a file)

```
[ 'a.exe', 'aa.exe' ]
```

Any way to get the file extension or get whether its a folder or file (that will help too)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE0oD.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to 'file-system' module.

This is tutorial that use this module.

```
fs.recurse('path', function(filepath, relative, filename) { });
 
fs.recurse('path', [
  '*.css',
  '**/*.js', 
  'path/*.html',
  '!**/path/*.js'
], function(filepath, relative, filename) {  
  if (filename) {
  // it's file
  } else {
  // it's folder
  }
});
 
//  Only using files
fs.recurse('path', function(filepath, relative, filename) {  
  if (!filename) return;
});
```

You can find more info in [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-system)